# How to access remote MBean server from jboss as 7 through RMI

Tags: jboss7.x, jmx

I have two applications, one is deployed in jboss as 7, another is a java application (Camel).
The camel has an exposed JMX service:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://172.20.30.85:19999/jmxrmi/camel
```

now, I need to access it from a EJB(jboss as 7). I have tried the following two ways, but both are fialed.

A) works well with jboss as 5.x:

```
JMXServiceURL target = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + host + ":"  + port.toString() + "/jmxrmi/camel");
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(target);
```

got exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: rmi://172.20.30.85:19999/jmxrmi/camel --  service jboss.naming.context.java.rmi:."172.20.30.85:19999".jmxrmi.camel
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:103)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:241)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1929)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1896)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:286)
```

B)

```
JMXServiceURL target = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:remoting-jmx://172.20.30.85:19999/jmxrmi/camel");
```

got exception:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "endpoint" read-1) JBREM000200:  Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting  connection 79f4a60c to sha-lri-pc-161/172.20.30.85:19999
11:33:44,415 WARN  [com.lombardrisk.reform.process.api.ProcessInspectorBean] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-29) Could not connect to integration MBean server:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
at   org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalRemotingConnect(RemotingConnector.java:235)
at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalConnect(RemotingConnector.java:148)
at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.connect(RemotingConnector.java:99)
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
at com.lombardrisk.reform.process.api.ProcessInspectorBean.getIntegrationMBeanServerConnection(ProcessInspectorBean.java:328)
at com.lombardrisk.reform.process.api.ProcessInspectorBean.getRoutes(ProcessInspectorBean.java:486)
```

Is there anyone who can guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try it on your local computer first.  Might be some network issue regarding connecting to 172.20.30.85:19999

Comment: Looks like it's same with this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612245/cant-connect-to-tigase-with-jmx-from-jboss-7-x?rq=1

Comment: @djb , Both JBoss and Camel run on my local, i.e. same machine.

I can access Camel's service in java application via this,
`JMXServiceURL target = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + host + ":"  + port.toString() + "/jmxrmi/camel");
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(target)`

Comment: So, I bet it's to do with 172.20.30.85  - Try localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead? You're sure Camel is exposing JMX on 19999?